# What does the sign %<-% mean in R?

Tags: r

I am learning GAN with 
https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2018-08-26-eager-dcgan/. There is a line of code

```
c(train_images, train_labels) %<-% mnist$train
```

What is `%<-%`? What does it mean?

Comment: See [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/zeallot/man/operator.html). It's an assignment operator in package `zeallot`. It can be obtained with `devtools::install_github('nteetor/zeallot')`.

Comment: `%<-%` is not a built in function in R. It's a user-defined infix operator. Different packages may define this operator differently. It's important to know what packages you have loaded when running this code in order to understand what it does.